# Efficiently multiply packed self-adjoint matrices

Tags: matrix-multiplication, blas

In my project I need to repeatedly multiply self-adjoint matrices of sizes 1000 to 20 000. This constitutes the main computational bottleneck of the code and needs to be performed as fast as possible.

The matrices are stored in an upper-triangular packed form as vectors. My best algorithm is as follows.

1. Unpack 1st vector `AP` into an upper triangular matrix `A`,
2. Unpack 2nd vector `BP` into a general matrix `B`,
3. Use `ZHEMM` from the vendor `BLAS` library to perform complex matrix multiplication.

One can also write a code working exclusively with `AP`, and `BP` (avoiding steps 1 and 2), but will it be faster than `BLAS`? Is there any chance to make it faster. It does not matter for me whether `C`, `FORTRAN` or `C++` is used.